# Asus Q502L Elantech ETD0108 touchpad not working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, touchpad, asus, elantech

My touch pad on the Asus Q502L is not working with Ubuntu 14.04. My peer who has the exact same machine with the same version installed is currently working. I read to update the BIOS and I have the most current BIOS as well as driver updates. Any suggestions to get this to work? As stated my peers works with the exact same machine and install. The touchpad is active and show in xinput list and it is turned on.

```
dmesg | grep pnp
[    0.245483] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.245716] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ETD0108 SYN0a00 SYN0002 PNP0f03 PNP0f13 PNP0f12 (active)
[    0.245753] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)
[    0.245872] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.246951] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices


xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101b   id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question andd add output of `xinput` and `dmesg | grep pnp` terminal commands.

Comment: xinput and dmesg | grep pnp added to the edit

Comment: And what is your kernel version. `uname -r` ?

Comment: 3.16.0-38-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the driver. Run in terminal.

Download [THIS FILE](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1022340) to your home folder. Run in terminal

```
tar -xf psmouse-etd0108.tar.gz
sudo cp -r ~/psmouse-etd0108 /usr/src
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v etd0108
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And reboot

Comment: got file and it is extracted into home dir. When I run first command I get:cp: cannot stat ‘/home/keith/psmouse-edt0108’: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have a `psmouse-edt0108` directory? I updated the answer. You need to extract that directory from archive. Not files in it.

Comment: I do not I just have the file you specified to download in the home folder. Using the new updated comment you posted tar -xf psmouse-etd0108.tar.gz worked fine but the next command failed.  sudo cp -r ~/psmouse-edt0108 /usr/src
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/keith/psmouse-edt0108’: No such file or directory

Comment: What file did you download? It should be `psmouse-etd0108.tar.gz`?

Comment: /home/keith/psmouse-etd0108.tar.gz

Comment: There was a typo. Fixed. I wrote `edt` instead of `etd`.

Comment: sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v etd0108
sudo: dkms: command not found

Comment: Added another command.

Comment: I will add it to ppa, to make it easier, if somebody asks.